# Multitable constraints in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with 2 tables (primary keys are in italic) :

- ROOM (*ROOM_ID*, DAY, HOUR)
- RESERVATION (*CUSTOMER_ID*, *ROOM_ID*, DATE)

The first table describes room availability and the second reservations made by the customers.

Now let's say that I've inserted 3 rows into `ROOM` :

```
3898   WEDNESDAY   2.00
3454   MONDAY      1.00
3563   MONDAY      1.00
```

and two rows into `RESERVATION`:

```
0898   3454   05-09-2019 
0567   3898   05-08-2019
```

Now I'd like to create a constraint which doesn't allow a customer who has already reserved a room to reserve another room which is available at the same time!

Then if I try to insert:

```
0567   3563   05-10-2019
```

I would get an error because according to the first table rooms 3454 and 3563 are both available at 1.00.

Thanks !

Comment: I think the only automatic solution would be to have a trigger, which I do not recommend. This is something you should check in either your application or inside of the stored procedure that does the insert.

Comment: MYSQL and SQLSERVER are very different. You should remove the inappropriate tag or if you want a solution for both you should say so.

Comment: There is no useful relationship between reservation and room since room has no idea of the date available and reservation has no idea of the time required. Given this  just create a unique key in reservation on customer_id and date.

Comment: "Now I'd like to create a constraint which doesn't allow a customer who has already reserved a room to reserve another room which is available at the same time!" - like someone saying "oh, we come with kids, please give me two rooms"? That requirement at least sounds pretty bad to me and totally does not take into account real world scenarios where you DO reserve multiple rooms for one customer. Be careful you really want this - because I can think of a multititude of reasons I did reserve multiple rooms at the same time.

Comment: To add to that, your names do not reflect your model. "Room" is a poor name because it reflects the availability of a room for a given (but very flawed) time period. Note that "period" is implied in your description - is that really a limitation of your system? You should really think about your model, as the others have already stated.

Comment: You can achieve this via denormalization and composite foreign key. However, I am not sure you want this, the example does not make sense to me and it seems ill designed.

Comment: I hear you all, in fact it's not a real word scenario that's clearly not the point here, its just an example to explain to you what I'm trying to get. I tried to make myself clear about what I want here. The model is definitely not complete it's just an exercise....

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'd like to create a constraint which doesn't allow a customer who has already reserved a room to reserve another room which is available at the same time.

I interpret this as saying that a customer can reserve only one room on each date.  If so, you can do this with a unique index/constraint in `reservation` on (`customer_id`, `date`):

```
create unique index unq_reservation_customer_date on reservation(customer_id, date);
```

This guarantees that a given customer can only reserve one room on each date.

Comment: How does this prevent insertion of "0567   3563   05-10-2019" record?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek . . . If you already have a row for 0567/05-10-2019 in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two ways to create true constraint:

1. You create materialized view of both tables and add unique index on this view.
2. You add ROOM_DAY and ROOM_HOUR columns into RESERVATION table and
   add a composite foreign key constraint to enforce data integrity:

> ```
> ALTER TABLE RESERVATION WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RESERVATION_ROOM 
> FOREIGN KEY(ROOM_ID, ROOM_DAY, ROOM_HOUR)
> REFERENCES ROOM (ROOM_ID, DAY, HOUR)
> ```

beware you have to enable it too. Then you can add unique index on RESERVATION table.